# Magento 2.3.5 : How to remove specific product from recently viewed product list

Tags: magento2, collection, recently-viewed

I have display recently viewed product slider on product page using Magento default widget. But, I want to remove product from recent viewed product collection.

How to remove that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: No..............